# When I run command "make:auth", and reload Laravel, the links show but when I click them it says "Not Found"

Tags: php, laravel

So I've downloaded Laravel 5.5, and I ran the following command 
in my terminal. `php artisan make:auth` and when I reloaded Laravel, the links for Login and Register show up but when I click them, it says Not Found.

I've tried resetting artisan and deleting my tables, and re-migrating artisan too, but none of them work.

```
php artisan make:auth
```

And heres my web.php file.

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});



Route::get('/post', 'PostController@index');

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

Comment: Try adding `Auth::routes();` to **/routes/web.php**.

Comment: I already have that in my file, unless you mean add it again at the end of the line of code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your project's directory tree after executing it?

Did you run the migrations?

If you did all that it should scaffold all of the routes and views you need for authentication. But if it still does not work properly, then you might have to uninstall Laravel and install a fresh distro.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add your web.php file under the routes directory please ?

It's probably a route problem.

Thank you.

Comment: Okay I added it in.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of anchor tag is not work...it may be some syntex error or spelling mistake 
maybe ragister.blade.php have some problem

Comment: I have Laravel 5.5, it might be because of some very outdated php code. If I update Laravel will the code be more updated or just the same but with more features? What I'm saying is it might be why the files aren't working as the should.